# Can't find modules required in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was going through the React codebase, and I noticed how React's `require` doesn't quite behave like in Nodejs. I don't get what's going on here.

Looking at line 19 on ReactClass.js for instance, there's a `require('emptyObject')`, but emptyObject isn't listed in package.json, nor does it say anywhere where that module's coming from.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js#L19

I did find ["emptyObject" on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emptyObject), but the API there seems different from the one used in React; the `.isEmpty` grepped in React isn't related to emptyObject.

So where is emptyObject getting loaded from, and how is React's `require` doing what it's doing? This is not intuitive. At all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The location of the `emptyObject` module which React refers to is https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/core/emptyObject.js#L9 Note that it doesn't follow the CommonJS module system.

> To make it easier for Facebook to share and consume our own JavaScript. Primarily this will allow us to ship code without worrying too much about where it lives, keeping with the spirit of @providesModule but working in the broader JavaScript ecosystem.

From https://github.com/facebook/fbjs#purpose

The way of defining a module by adding `@providesModule` in the license header and loading those modules with `require` in Node is called Haste, a customized module system built for Facebook's open source projects.

In fact, unless you would like to understand the inner workings of React or contribute to Facebook's open source projects, you don't need to know that. In other words, it's not recommended to use Haste to write your own project.

Along the same lines, the `invariant` module being loaded at line 10 of `ReactClass.js` is declared at https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/__forks__/invariant.js#L9

As far as I know, both Eclipse and WebStorm don't support Haste so IDE can't help. But with Haste, the name of file and module should be the same, so you can find a module by searching for the filename, i.e. double shift in Webstorm and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> in Eclipse. However, the `emptyObject` you asked about or `invariant` are not part of React so it's still cumbersome to find their origin.

Otherwise, there is a team that shares and organizes what they learn from hacking React that I contribute to occasionally and they have linked those `require`s by following Haste to the corresponding origin file e.g. https://annot.io/github.com/facebook/react/blob/cc3dc21/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js?l=19 You may want to see that.

Comment: For the details of Haste, see https://facebook.github.io/react/contributing/codebase-overview.html#custom-module-system

Comment: I don't use any of those IDEs but I suppose `find`ing inside the facebook/fbjs dir will do? The annot.io link is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: It could get annoying dealing with a dynamic language like JavaScript w/o an IDE, especially on projects with facebookisms like this. What do you use then?

Comment: I'm a recent, but devout, follower of emacs. It seems to work pretty well with JavaScript - even React, though further experience may prove different

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed how React's `require` doesn't quite behave like in Nodejs.

Right. Facebook has its own module loader. All modules have unique identifiers, provided by the `@providesModule` directive in each module. This allows you to use the identifier to load the module, instead of the file path.

Of course that doesn't work in a Node.js based environment. So when React or any other Facebook project is published to npm, all `require` calls are rewritten automatically to something that Node understands.

This functionality is provided by [fbjs](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/446badb82d7774a9d23df70b51cb04abb97e11bc/packages/fbjs/src/core/emptyObject.js) which contains shared dependencies and build helpers for all Facebook projects. [This is where you find the `emptyObject` module](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/446badb82d7774a9d23df70b51cb04abb97e11bc/packages/fbjs/src/core/emptyObject.js).

If you look at [React's gulp file](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/abeae306e5eb53ec6354ff625f10b90aa79645ae/gulpfile.js), you can see how the module maps are constructed and that a custom Babel plugin is used to convert all `require` calls.

Comment: So the gulp file was how `require` was doing what it was doing. Thanks. I'm picking @donghwan-kim's answer however for mentioning Haste and various ways to find the target modules.